# MFCC Sampling frequency

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy, scikit-learn

I want to obtain MFCC values of my wav file. Here is my code:

```
> import numpy as np 
> import scipy.io.wavfile 
> from scikits.talkbox.features import mfcc
> sr1,x1=scipy.io.wavfile.read("filename.wav")
> ceps1,mspec1,spec1=mfcc(x1)
```

The value of sr1=22050. But in the scikit.talkbox library the mfcc() uses the fs=16000 as a default. How can I fix it? or Does it create any problem for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [the docstring for `mfcc`](https://github.com/cournape/talkbox/blob/master/scikits/talkbox/features/mfcc.py#L47).  The signature of the function is

```
def mfcc(input, nwin=256, nfft=512, fs=16000, nceps=13):
```

As you noted in the question, the default value of `fs` is 16000.  You can override that by using `fs=sr1` in your code:

```
ceps1, mspec1, spec1 = mfcc(x1, fs=sr1)
```

(For more information about keyword arguments of python functons, see, for example, [*4.7.2. Keyword Arguments* in the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).)